# how to add customfield in filter

Tags: drupal-6, filter, view, custom-fields

i have created one custom field on view i want add filter on it how can i add it to filter

here is problem of adding filter on custom field  of view

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a "Views filter", you have access to all of them via Filter -> Content -> List of all content available including your own types

If you are talking about the module "Views Custom Field" than you can't use a filter on it since these are not related to the core and therefore not registered with the views core. Furthermore, the purpose of this module is to extend the content and not the filtering functionallity.

Comment: i have used Views Custom Field. i want filter on view , so is there any another module for that which filter custom field of my view.another way to filter custom field of view?

Comment: I don't knopw if there are any since the custom fields are not a rather "clean" (but sometimes very usefull) solution. You could check the drupal.org forums if there are any other possibilities but I don't know of any.